# Testing Rest API Callouts using Named Credentials

Tags: rest, salesforce, apex, apex-code

I am trying to test the API Callouts from Salesforce using the Named Credentials. I have setup the Named Credentials and OAuth Providers and was able to quickly test the Authentication within Named Credentials

[image]

I am trying to write the Apex Class to see if I can retrieve records from the Rest API I am not how to test Executing this Anonymously

```
public with sharing class RetrieveD365Data {
    public RetrieveD365Data() {
              Http http = new Http();
              HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
              req.setEndpoint('callout:Dev_D365/data/Customers');
              req.setMethod('GET');
              req.setTimeout(30000);
              HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
              System.debug('Response Body===========' + res.getBody());
    }
}
```

I tried to run this code on the DEV Console
[image]

But I am getting Line: 6, Column: 1
System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable" . Please help me with this as I am new to Salesforce.

I am just confused as the Authentication was successful (Says Authenticated Status) while setting up the Named Credentials. But making the callout receiving the error unavailable

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to make callouts straight out of constructor. What if you're in a context that doesn't allow callouts (in a trigger - you'd need @future method for example, in a batch job you'd have to implement AllowCallouts interface). Better to have it in a separate method.

But looking at your code you should be able to simply go `new RetrieveD365Data();` in the dev console?

Comment: Can you please look in to my updated question. I tried to execute the code in the Execute Anonymous window in DEV Console and I am getting 503 error. But with the Named Credentials I see the status as Authenticated

Comment: It should work, you might have to experiment, read the docs of the service you're calling. You used "Named Principal" so same username/password/whatever for whole org, correct? Can you experiment with manual OAuth2 message (POST to certain url with JSON body containing username, password, client id, secret, that kind of stuff), from Apex or from Postman for example. It's hard to tell without knowing what service it is. Is OAuth the only option? Can the mutual trust be established with certificates? Look what URL is generated in debug log, maybe it goes to wrong address?